# desktop python script retrieve sms messages sent to android device

Tags: python, android, sms

I have a web scraper written in python/selenium that runs daily on a home server. One of the sites I'm scraping have recently introduced 2FA which overall I'm in favour of however the downside is that it has broken my automation as now a one-time-passcode is sent via SMS to my mobile number - which needs to be typed in before the script can continue. To get my script fully automated again I need a means for my desktop python script to poll my android device for its SMS messages.

I looked at Twilio however the docs suggest it doesn't fit my use case as;

> Hosted SMS provides a method for customers to use Twilio ... to send and receive messages on voice-enabled numbers they already own ... Hosted SMS supports USA & Canada in Beta. Mobile numbers are not supported.

Google have the `SMS Retriever API` which also doesn't fit my purpose as it requires a custom hash code in the message body and the `SMS User Consent API` requires the user to tap the screen to approve each request (which of course isn't fully automated).

The quickest haphazard method I can think of to get these OTPs to my python script would be to write a simple discrete mobile app with permission to access SMS and create the following workflow:

- have the desktop python script pause when it reaches a 2FA screen and listen on a specified UDP/TCP port
- have the mobile app simply looking for messages from a target number (or with a target phrase)
- when such a message arrives the app would encrypt the message text, and
- send it via UDP/TCP to the aforementioned port on my home server
- let the script decrypt and parse for the OTP (or timeout after x minutes)

Ideally the only thing that would hinder the workflow is if my phone happened to be off at the time that the script runs.

... rather than cludging this together I am wondering if anyone can recommend a better means (or API) of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look into https://wammu.eu/, supported phones https://wammu.eu/phones/